# Unable to build .net core AspnetBoilerplate Starter Template

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have spent quite a time trying to load the Initial Project generated by the AspnetBoilerplate startup template all to no avail. This is a .net core template (JQuery with MVC) with Target Cross platform.
See error sample below

[image: Error]

I installed the dotnet core 2 for VS 2017. The project won't just build. I can not see anything related to NetStandard, yet that seems to be what the project supports
Any help i can get will be appreciated

Comment: Make sure you’re running Visual Studio 2017 15.3 (run the VS installer to make sure you’re up to date)

Comment: will try this now

Comment: Are you running VS 15.3.3?  Did you install .NET Core SDK? https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core ... I downladed a fresh copy and built without errors

Comment: Thanks I updated Visual Studio 2017 to 15.3.3 and wola. it took a while to download, but it was worth it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error on first build after downloading project from ASP Net Boiler Plate with ASP.Net Core 1.x Multi Page Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176159/error-on-first-build-after-downloading-project-from-asp-net-boiler-plate-with-as)

Comment: That is impressive as the possible duplicate, was asked 10 minutes after mine. So that is a duplicate of this

Comment: Erm, [nope](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271329/question-marked-as-duplicate-of-the-question-asked-at-a-later-date).