# Error on first build after downloading project from ASP Net Boiler Plate with ASP.Net Core 1.x Multi Page Web Application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I am using visual studio 2017. I just download project from asp net boiler plate and open it in vs 17. When i rebuild the solution i got the big list of 370 errors.
Few are listed below due to the content limits.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Abp 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Abp.TestBase 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp.TestBase 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Abp.AutoMapper 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp.AutoMapper 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0.            0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Abp.AutoMapper 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp.AutoMapper 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0.            0
>   Error       Package Abp 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Abp.Castle.Log4Net 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp.Castle.Log4Net 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Abp.AutoMapper 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp.AutoMapper 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 2.0.0 supports:
>     - net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
>     - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)          0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Abp 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0.            0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools 2.0.0 supports: netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Abp.AutoMapper 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp.AutoMapper 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Abp.AutoMapper 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp.AutoMapper 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Abp 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Abp.Castle.Log4Net 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp.Castle.Log4Net 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Abp 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Castle.LoggingFacility.MsLogging 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Castle.LoggingFacility.MsLogging 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Abp.AspNetCore 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp.AspNetCore 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Abp.ZeroCore 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp.ZeroCore 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Abp 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)           0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Abp.AspNetCore 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Abp.AspNetCore 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)         0
>   Error       Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 2.0.0 supports:
>     - net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
>     - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)          0
>   Blockquote

Looking for help!. Thanks

Comment: [This template](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates)? That one appears to be only available for ASP.NET Core 1.x. – Make sure, you’re running an updated Visual Studio (version 15.3), and make sure you also installed a 2.0 [.NET Core SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd)

Comment: Yes the template you have mentioned. I have downloaded a sample step by step guide project for the same scenario from here (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1115763/Using-ASP-NET-Core-Entity-Framework-Core-and-ASP-N). which is running fine in my Visual Studio 2017. which indicates my V.S studio is updated. I downloaded several project from boilerplate but each one giving me long list of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can say that the latest version is being compiled successfully without errors.
[image]

Are you running VS 15.3.3?

Did you install .NET Core SDK? https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

Comment: Thanks. Your answer help a lot. But actually aspnetboilerplate team should look into the matter. Because on the startup template https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates Asp.Net Core 1.x is mentioned on active tab. But the downloaded project targets to Asp.Net Core 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I just build it. Using VS 2017, net core 2.
There is still one thing that missing for me which is the Abp.AutoMapper.
Solve it by just update it to latest stable version through Nuget. And rebuild.